# How to redirect lowercase to uppercase

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I have a WordPress blog and I made subfolder like this

```
https://example.com/Tourism
```

but when I open this URL with lowercase "t" it shows me 404 not found error:

```
https://example.com/tourism
```

this subfolder has a lot of posts and when I open "tourism" (with lowercase "t") it shows me 404 not found.

How can I redirect all "tourism" word to "Tourism" with `.htaccess`?

Comment: What have you tried? This would seem to be a relatively simple redirect? However, if you are using WordPress then maybe this should be done inside WordPress, not `.htaccess`?

Comment: It is far easier to use all lowercase URLs than mixed case URLs.   The rules for redirecting to all lowercase are trivial compared to the rules for figuring out the correct case for each URL individually.   I worked for TripAdvisor and they had mixed case URLs like that.   They are a big pain to support and don't have much if any advantage.

Comment: @MrWhite
i didn't try any code.
how can i do this with wordpress?
I'm new in this kind of wordpress.

Comment: yes i made this subfolder a few month ago and this kind of urls is indexed in google and changing it may cause problems. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: In wordpress, change the slug for the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `.htaccess`, to redirect all URLs that start `/tourism` to `/Tourism` then you can do something like the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the root, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
# Redirect "/tourism" to "/Tourism"
RewriteRule ^t(ourism.*) /T$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 when you are sure it's working OK.

For a WordPress specific answer (ie. to redirect *late* and not interfere with "normal" traffic) then you should ask this on our WordPress sister site at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/